# Spring Batch Jsr 352, manage processor skip outside/before skip listener

Tags: spring-batch, listeners, jsr352

I am trying to find a way to manage a skip scenario in the process listener (or could be read or write listener as well).  What I have found is the skip listener seems to be executed after the process listener's on error method.  This means that I might be handling the error in some way with out knowledge that it is an exception to be skipped.

Is there some way to know that a particular exception is being skipped out side the skip listener?  Something that could be pulled into the process listener or possibly else where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach I found to do this was just to add property to the step and then wire in the step context where i needed it.

```
<step id="firstStep">
   <properties> <property name="skippableExceptions" value="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"/> </properties>
</step>
```

This was not a perfect solution but the skip exceptions only seem to be set in StepFactoryBean and Tasklet and are not directly accessible.

For code in my listeners

```
@Inject
StepContext stepContext;
.
.
.
Properties p = stepContext.getProperties();
String exceptions = p.getProperty("skippableExceptions");
```